# Can not connect to Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04, but I can not connect to my wifi.

I am completely new to Ubuntu, can some one please help me out with this?

Comment: Type in the command `lspci` in the terminal window(ctrl+alt+t) and post the answer here

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)